# Does writing JSON in a single line create any problem?

Tags: python, json

I have used json.dump() without indent

```
with open (JSONfilename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
f.close()
```

This saves all of JSON data in a single line. I have done this because I noticed that using indent=4 for formatting JSON file increases it size. Is saving big JSON file in single line ok or will I encounter any problem in future?

Edit: Does it effect on saving, loading or parsing time?

Comment: It should be OK, it's still valid JSON. You can try loading the JSON again (`json.load`) and see that it works

Comment: No, it doesn't create any problem, it's perfectly normal. Multiline is only used to make it readable to humans.

Comment: Why do you think they would make the default be a problem?

Comment: It’s perfectly ok, the good thing about JSON is that it is structured enough and doesn’t really care about the formatting. The indent in particular is just for readability.

Comment: It’s very common to not only store JSON without newline, but also store multiple JSONs in the same file, each on a single line. This is usually a lot more efficient than storing an array because you don’t have to load the whole file in memory to access each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, *people* will have trouble reading it, if you consider that a problem.

The JSON parser ignores whitespace outside of quotation marks.

Comment: Well there are several tools that are able to load large json files better if there are line breaks present..though just for the json handling code/modules/parsers it doesn't matter. But in real world, we do get situation where you need to check the json file by using some utility for some troubleshooting.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran — really?  I would be skeptical (in general) of any JSON tool that faltered without whitespace.

Comment: It won't falter, I said it will handle it better, for instance the buffered read and loading such lengthy json strings into their buffer and eventually showing in their UI is `better`

Answer (score 0):

The format of .json file will be okay.
I want to add one 'Important@ thing. While reading the same file, json.load module only can read till 226538 column length in one line. If you data is much larger, It will cause this extra data problem in one line.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense: the parser doesn’t care about newlines, they are just space characters. I just used `json.load` to read a file with a line of 100 millions characters without any issue.

Comment: I was facing this problem, and problem is solved after doing above mentioned solution.